# Filtering a form with subforms in Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007

In a SQL database I have a table, `Table1`. This table is related to another table, `Table2` which in turn is related to `Table3`. There is a query `Query1` that selects certain records from `Table1`.

This database is linked to in an Access database project

A form `Table1Data` is based on `Table1`, with a datasheet containing related `Table2` data (and subsequently `Table3` data). This form is opened by another form (`Switchboard`). The problem comes when the form is opened. I want the form to be filtered, but when I set up a macro and open the form and set the Filter to `Query1`, the data in the form is not filtered. Why does this happen, is this not the way to do it? `Query1` selects all the columns from `Table1`, so mismatching columns should not be an issue.

Additionally I want to lock it down - only certain people can execute `Query1`, same with other queries (`Query2`, `Query3` etc). So they can only edit the data that they are permitted to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preferred solution is to set the recordsource in the Form Open event.  This gives me the most control over what is going on.

Here is my boilerplate for doing this.  It also includes looking up the OpenArgs which are passed on calling the form.  You can just comment out or remove the If/Then statement if you aren't looking to specify anything from the calling form in your SQL.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    ' Comments  :
    ' Parameters: Cancel -
    ' Modified  :
    ' --------------------------------------------------

    On Error GoTo Err_Form_Open

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strVariable As String
    Dim strDateVariable As String
    Dim dteDateVariable As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer

    'Get variables from Left and right of | in OpenArgs
    If Not (IsNull(Me.OpenArgs)) Then

        i = InStr(1, Me.OpenArgs, "|")
        n = Len(Me.OpenArgs)

        strVariable = Left(Me.OpenArgs, n - (n - i + 1))

        strDateVariable = Right(Me.OpenArgs, (n - i))

        dteDateVariable = CDate(strDateVariable)

    Else

        GoTo Exit_Form_Open

    End If

    strSQL = "SELECT   ... " _
           & "FROM     ... " _
           & "WHERE (((Field1)='" & strVariable & "') " _
           & "  AND  ((Field2)=#" & dteDateVariable & "#));"

    Me.RecordSource = strSQL

    Me.Requery

Exit_Form_Open:

    Exit Sub

Err_Form_Open:

    Select Case Err.Number
        Case Else
            Call ErrorLog(Err.Number, Err.Description, "Form_Open", "frmName", Erl)
            GoTo Exit_Form_Open
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have an example macro OpenForm action that results in this running and the variables set base on it?

Comment: Get away from macros as soon as possible. They lack versatility and have no error correction. Macros are for novices. After you've used Access for a few weeks, you shouldn't be creating any, except for the two functions for which they are required (AutoExec and AutoKeys).

Comment: The OpenForm action is going to fire when you open the form Table1Data that you describe in your question.  The code will execute setting the Recordsource to your SQL string and then the .Requery will cause the form to draw based upon the new RecordSource.

Additionally, I agree with David Fenton that you shouldn't use Macros, except that I won't even use them in AutoExec and AutoKeys, because I just find other ways around those issues.